# HttpWebResponse req.GetResponse() failes

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

i have the following problem. when I call the getResponse () method, I get the following error message: The underlying connection was closed: Unexpected error when sending. (.Net Framework 4.0)

```
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/rest-api/v2/stations/Bonn.json");
            req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            req.Accept = "application/json";
            req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            string result = null;
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();}
```

Comment: Post the *full* exception message including the call stack. You can get this easily with `Exception.ToString()`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what if you try plain `http` instead of `https`? I see that URL supports both. Could you please give it a spin?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is an extremely quick way to jump at conclusions. It's **nothing** like that. It's just a test: if it works over plain HTTP, the problem could be due to the TLS protocol version, in which case the answer, including one for .NET 4.0, is already here on SO. EDIT for your edit: it is indeed a security bug on the part of the site, but here we're debugging, and you have to try things to pin the problem down.

Comment: @s.m. sorry. The way the comment was written it looked like you suggested the OP use `http`. I hope the OP doesn't try this for anything other than debugging, even if it works

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no problem. And by all means, this can't be emphasized enough: **OP, only every do this to troubleshoot**. And if you have any contact with the owners of that web service, please let them know that they probably want to redirect http traffic to https, because as it stands, they have a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your framework to a supported version. The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2, although you should prefer 4.6 at least.

If you check that URL, you'll see that the target site uses TLS1.2, as it should. TLS1.2 support was added in .NET 4.5. It became a default in 4.6. .NET 4.0 just *doesn't* support TLS1.2

In the .NET versions that don't use TLS1.2 as a default, you can request it by setting the [ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) setting :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

In .NET 4.0 You could use a hack and install the .NET 4.5.2 runtime. The `Tls12` value doesn't exist, but you can still set numeric value :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

I advise against this though. There aren't any serious compatibility issues between 4.0 and 4.5.2. By running a 4.0 application on a 4.5.2 runtime you'd get all of them but none of the benefits.

Comment: ServicePointManager. security protocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; fixed my problem. In the future i will change to  .Net 4.5.2 Framework 4.5.2.